# Why are dubbels generally dark while most tripels are not?

Tags: trappist, colour, dubbel, tripel

In my experience, dubbels are often fairly dark, brown ales, while tripels are much clearer and lighter (of colour).

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Color tends to come primarily from the malt bill used (darker roasted malts lending darker color to a beer).  In the case of Belgian beers, a "candi" sugar (derived from beets) may used as an additive, and different styles use different types of candi sugars.  For dubbels in particular, the candi is a darker variety, made with a (more) substantial dose of molasses, which would darken the beer further.  A tripel uses a candi with less molasses.